# How to display custom taxonomy

Tags: custom-taxonomy, templates, taxonomy, template-hierarchy

I have created `city` taxonomy in back end and i have added mumbai,pune,nashik city in `city` taxonomy like bellow snipe.

My problem is that when i click the city for example `mumbai` i want display the all product in the `mumbai` city which i have set from the product tab means that product is in `mumbai` city category.

I have tried with bellow code but not getting any thing.

Custom Taxonomies display

Template file used to render the Archive Index page for a Custom Taxonomy

```
taxonomy-{taxonomy}-{term}.php
```

As regrading above code i have changed my file name to `taxonomy-city-city.php` but its not working.tell me if have any body idea about this issue.

Site Link:-  [Click Here](http://planmymedicaltrip.com/new/) and Click on select your city button

1) Taxonomy city:-

[image: taxonmycity]

2) Added cities in Taxonomy `city`

[image: city]

3) Taxonomy terms details

[image: terms]

Comment: Did you try with `taxonomy-city.php`?

Comment: i have tried it its not working for me

Comment: Are you sure `city` is the taxonomy name for your custom taxonomy? Can you please confirm?

Comment: yes i have attached snipe in question you can check aloso

Comment: Have you tried a template file `city.php` ? Basing this of 'category' being a taxonomy and there's `category.php`.

Comment: Also, have you bound your CPT (Custom Post Type) `products` to link to the object (term/taxonomy) of `city`? If not, do so as well. Have a look at the "taxonomies" Argument (halfway down the page) [here](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/register_post_type).

Comment: i have added taxonomy terms details in question with snipe check it

Answer (score 0):

Once you have created custom taxonomies in WordPress, the next step is to display them on post pages. Fortunately, this is a matter of adding the following single line of code to the single.php (located in the theme folder):

```
<?php the_terms( $post->ID, ‘topics’, ‘Topics: ‘, ‘, ‘, ‘ ‘ ); ?>
```

By default custom taxonomies use the archive.php template to display posts. However, you can create a custom archive display for custom taxonomies by creating taxonomy-{taxonomy-slug}.php,where taxonomy-slug refers to slug of custom taxonomy.

I have found it here https://www.wpblog.com/create-custom-taxonomies-in-wordpress/